# preview tab missing on RDLC report visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Please help iam using visual studio 2019 but iam on trying to design RDLC reports the Preview tab is  missing how can i activate it thank in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You use RDL Report Builder in the past right?

I'd remember that tool has a preview function.

But there are no `Preview` functions in Visual Studio version AFAIK, you can make a small project or code to feed and generate report.